# selecting tag with a specific attribute(only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

I have the following document structure in :

```
...
...
<span class="clblue redcl turbocl">something</span>
<span class="clblue redcl turbocl">something</span>
<span class="clblue">something</span>
<span class="clblue">something</span>
...
...
```

In JavaScript (only) I want:
`document.querySelectorAll("span.clblue")` to give span with ONLY 'clblue' class NOT all the span(s) with 'clblue' and also other classes.

Comment: So, only select the items that have a *single* class and that single class is `clblue`, is that correct?

Comment: check the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)  CSS pseudo-class. can be used for excludes

Comment: You know that adding your own attributes is invalid code, right? Use [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match a single class only rather than that class among others, you can use an attribute selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[class="clblue"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS select only one class name,

```
span[^="clblue"][$="clblue"] { ... }
```

Then We select it with JS,

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll("span[class^=clblue][class$=clblue]"); // NodeList

// x[0], x[1]... x[n]
```

Comment: The OP asked for JavaScript solutions only.

Comment: @Utkanos any JS solution will require using a CSS selector, so providing the selector isn't a wrong solution as we can easily later integrate it with querySelector()

Comment: Well that's like saying "it's currently an unusable answer but we *could* modify it to make it work". I get what you're saying - of course you can feed (most of) this answer to `querySelector`, but right now it's a CSS answer, not a JS one, and does not therefore match what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ok @Utkanos and owner of ques.. I edited my answer.

Comment: Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering out the querySelectorAll value?

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".clblue");
let filtered = Array.prototype.filter.call(items, function(node) {
    return node.classList.length === 1;
});
```

Comment: It's a bit of a waste to do this. CSS selector expressions already handle this, no need to use a CSS selector expression badly, only to post-fix the result.

Comment: Ok, how would you use the css selectors in this case then? :)

Comment: Just like [the other answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302628/selecting-tag-with-a-specific-attributeonly/#58302672).

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice it. On the other hand, it is a bit less universal. It only applies to spans what of course may be fine if the author intends such behavior. My solution applies to any element with a given class.

Comment: Which you can still specify with a CSS selector `"[class='clblue']"` will match any element. Again, you are throwing away the CSS selector functionality to re-implement it.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you.